# Flutter app crashes on start when applying fire base ( java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity)

Tags: firebase, flutter, gradle, android-multidex

I had started a new  project in flutter and i was applying fire store to it.

On following the steps to add my app to fire base it started to give error.

The error found in log cat when started app was

```
04-04 14:54:56.061 24084-24084/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.firestoreflutterchat, PID: 24084
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.firestoreflutterchat-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.firestoreflutterchat-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4869)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4461)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4401)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1270)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.firestoreflutterchat-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.firestoreflutterchat-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4854)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4461) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4401) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1270) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method
```

The app i am running on kit kat version device Xt1030

to remove this error i did some things in gradle and mostly described by others was multidex

so this is my gradle files :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
      //  maven { url 'https://github.com/yongjhih/android-gradle-plugin.m2/raw/master/' }
        jcenter()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // Add this line

       // classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        //com.google.android.gms to 11.4.2.
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and gradle app:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
// Add this line
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

//    compileOptions {
//        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION
//        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION 8
//    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'

    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.firestoreflutterchat"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
  //      testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
//        ndk {
//            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
//        }
        multiDexEnabled true



//        productFlavors {
//            dev {
//                // Enable pre-dexing to produce an APK that can be tested on
//                // Android 5.0+ without the time-consuming DEX build processes.
//                minSdkVersion 21
//                flavorDimensions "versionCode"
//            }
//            prod {
//                // The actual minSdkVersion for the production version.
//                minSdkVersion 18
//                flavorDimensions "versionCode"
//            }
//        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')

            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}



dependencies {
    // add the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

And in manifest file it was told to change name :

```
android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
```

to

```
android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

or on another way of doing this

To add a class that extends flutter application

which on performing

```
package com.example.firestoreflutterchat

    import android.content.Context
    import androidx.multidex.MultiDex
    import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication


    class App : FlutterApplication() {

        override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
            super.attachBaseContext(base)
            MultiDex.install(this)
        }
    }
```

and then changing Android manifest from

```
android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
```

to

```
android:name=".App"
```

Now after doing all these still my app crash but with different error

```
04-05 18:22:18.266 10645-10645/com.example.firestoreflutterchat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.firestoreflutterchat, PID: 10645
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firestoreflutterchat/com.example.firestoreflutterchat.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.firestoreflutterchat.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.firestoreflutterchat.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2115)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Any ideas how to resolve this

Comment: can you post your MainActivity code?

Comment: i took different approach and solved it , removing multidex solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error previously occurs due to compatibility issues and with issues setting up on multidex. This has been since patched by the flutterfire team as mentioned on this [ticket](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/698#issuecomment-656176237). Also, setting up Firebase on Flutter is now easy with the use of [flutterfire_cli](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup)